# Making a simple car game with HTML5 canvas

Tags: jquery, html, animation, canvas

I'm having a play with HTML5 canvas, and for my first experiment I decided to try make a simple car animation with basic user input. I think I'm most of the way there with basic input and movement, but I just wanted to see if I could take it a bit further.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/mpxML/20/
(use arrow keys)

I have an image loading in, you can also see a black square which moves, that is the translate point, or where the car is steering from. I wanted to somehow create a drift effect which can be achieved at higher speeds etc. It also can turn when it's not moving, that isn't right.

Anyway, I just don't know what logic I need to make the car feel more semi-realistic.

Thanks

Comment: Not a helpful comment but just want to say nice work! I drove the car out of the frame and now i've lost it lol!!

Comment: Hey thanks haha. Yeh I need to get some boundaries working really!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To fix the turning you have to do something like this:

```
car.angle = car.angle - (car.handeling * car.speed/car.topSpeed);
```

this will prevent from turning when speed is 0 and will fix the reverse turning

To get drift effects you should move the car's rotation center forward and allow the car to rotate over it self without really turning

Comment: That worked really well! Now when I'm not moving, I can't turn, when I am moving, I can get a tight turning circle. But when I'm going fast I want the handling efficiency to be lower. I was thinking of doing (handling / speed). I wish I was better at figuring it out.. The problem with that is, once you go in reverse, the handling messes up etc. >.<

Comment: If you are going to develop a stationary race track (no panning) then drift is really hard. I already messed around 2d racing a few years ago and I couldn't manage drift very well. It either was very subtle that you could hardly notice it or it was noticable and made handling extremely hard.

Answer (score 4):

Great little demo, love it!  I don't drive, these are my ideas.  I recommend experimenting, you don't *have* to go for realism - remember you are making a game, you want to go for fun :)

**Reversing**

I would make reverse work properly, when you reverse it doesn't turn in the direction I expect from traditional car movement.

**Drifting**

This would be triggered when the speed/angle of turning is at a certain amount.  Once these conditions have been met you could do something like prevent any more turning (by locking the current direction) and angle the car ~30o from the direction until the accelerate key is unpressed

**Turning**

I'm not a driver, but I would think your turning angle would be tighter when you are at a slower speed, perhaps create a simple formula for this, some sort of relationship between speed and turning amount.

**Shameless plug**

I have to disclose I work for [Scirra.com](http://www.scirra.com) and we have some software [Construct 2](http://www.scirra.com/construct2) ([Download](http://www.scirra.com/construct2/releases/new)), which is a Windows game making program for HTML5 games, it might be worth a look for you (depending on your objectives)!  It is extendible with JavaScript, so you can write your own movement behaviours and use others peoples, making car games is a lot more visual and easier (in our opinions any way!)

Comment: Hey, thanks for the feedback :) Good comments on the drifting, I'll try to work that in! I'm working on the turning circle and I'll also check out Construct 2 :)